# How to only keep the fastest ride in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this :

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'origin': ['town a', 'town a', 'town a','town a', 'town c', 'town c'],\
'destination': ['town b', 'town b', 'town b','town b','town b','town b'], \
'departure_hour': ['09:30', '09:45','10:00', '10:30','14:30', '15:30'],\
'arrival_hour': ['11:30', '10:50','12:00', '11:45','16:30', '19:30'],\
'date': ['29-09-2020', '29-09-2020','29-09-2020','29-09-2020','29-09-2020','29-09-2020']})

   origin destination departure_hour arrival_hour        date
0  town a      town b          09:30        11:30  29-09-2020
1  town a      town b          09:45        10:50  29-09-2020
2  town a      town b          10:00        12:00  29-09-2020
3  town a      town b          10:30        11:45  29-09-2020
4  town c      town b          14:30        16:30  29-09-2020
5  town c      town b          15:30        19:30  29-09-2020
```

We have ride between different cities with departure and arrival hour. I want to delete each row (trip) where we can take another trip later and arrival sooner.

So I want to have this result:

```
   origin destination departure_hour arrival_hour        date
1  town a      town b          09:45        10:50  29-09-2020
3  town a      town b          10:30        11:45  29-09-2020
4  town c      town b          14:30        16:30  29-09-2020
5  town c      town b          15:30        19:30  29-09-2020
```

I can do this with this method:

```
df['count_utility']=df.apply(lambda x : sum((df['departure_hour']>x.departure_hour)&(df['arrival_hour']<x.arrival_hour)&(df['origin']==x.origin)&(df['destination']==x.destination)&(df['date']==x.date)),axis=1)
```

and then apply a filter : `df['count_utility']==0`

But this method is too slow for my Dataframe which has 1 Million rows.

I think it could be faster using a group by on origin, destination and date but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: How about utilizing sorting?

Comment: I already use sort to delete trips with the same departure hour and different arrival hour, using df.sort_values(by=['departure_hour','arrival_hour''],inplace=True) and then drop_duplicates(subset=['date','origin', 'destination','departure_hour '], keep='first') and drop_duplicates(subset=['date','origin', 'destination','arrival_hour '], keep='last')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea with numpy broadcasting in custom function per groups in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
    a = x['departure_hour'].to_numpy()
    b = x['arrival_hour'].to_numpy()
    m = (a > a[:, None]) & (b < b[:, None])
    x['count_utility']  = m.sum(axis=1)
    return x

df = df.groupby(['origin','destination','date']).apply(f)
print (df)
   origin destination departure_hour arrival_hour        date  count_utility
0  town a      town b          09:30        11:30  29-09-2020              1
1  town a      town b          09:45        10:50  29-09-2020              0
2  town a      town b          10:00        12:00  29-09-2020              1
3  town a      town b          10:30        11:45  29-09-2020              0
4  town c      town b          14:30        16:30  29-09-2020              0
5  town c      town b          15:30        19:30  29-09-2020              0
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that's work. I test it on 100 000 rows and that's takes about 30 seconds where my solution takes more than 10 minutes on the same Dataframe. I will try this solution on the  global Dataframe this afternoon and published here the process time

Comment: So, I just try this on the global Dataframe, that takes about 200 seconds, it is ok for my purpose. I will close this tikcet if nobody published a faster way to do that today. Thank again @jezrael